# pandas: concatenate dataframes, forward-fill and multiindex on column data

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 csv files with the same column names, but different values.

The first column is the index (`time`) and one of the data columns is a unique identifier (`id`)

The index (`time`) is different for each csv file.

I have read the data into 2 dataframes using `read_csv`, giving me the following:

```
        +-------+------+-------+
        | id    | size | price |
+-------+-------+------+-------+
| time  |       |      |       |
+-------+-------+------+-------+
| t0    | ID1   | 10   | 110   |
| t2    | ID1   | 12   | 109   |
| t6    | ID1   | 20   | 108   |
+-------+-------+------+-------+

        +-------+------+-------+
        | id    | size | price |
+-------+-------+------+-------+
| time  |       |      |       |
+-------+-------+------+-------+
| t1    | ID2   |  9   |  97   |
| t3    | ID2   | 15   |  94   |
| t5    | ID2   | 13   | 100   |
+-------+-------+------+-------+
```

I would like to create a single large dataframe with entries for both, and use `ffill` to forward fill values from the previous time-step.

I am able to achieve this using a combination of `concat`, `sort` and `ffill`.

However, it requires renaming the columns of one of the dataframes first, so that there aren't name clashes

```
df2.columns = [ 'id', 'id2_size', 'id2_price' ]
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort().ffill()
```

This results in the following dataframe:

```
        +------+------+-------+----------+-----------+
        | id   | size | price | id2_size | id2_price |
+-------+------+------+-------+----------+-----------+
| time  |      |      |       |          |           |
+-------+------+------+-------+----------+-----------+
| t0    | ID1  | 10   | 110   |     nan  |     nan   |
| t1    | ID2  | 10   | 110   |      9   |      97   |
| t2    | ID1  | 12   | 109   |      9   |      97   |
| t3    | ID2  | 12   | 109   |     15   |      94   |
| t5    | ID2  | 12   | 109   |     13   |     100   |
| t6    | ID1  | 20   | 108   |     13   |     100   |
+-------+------+------+-------+----------+-----------+
```

My current method is fairly klunky in that I have to rename the columns of one of the dataframes.

I believe a better way to represent the data would be use a [multiindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/advanced.html) with the 2nd dimension's value coming from the `id` column.

The resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
        +--------------+--------------+
        | ID1          | ID2          |
        +------+-------+------+-------+
        | size | price | size | price |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
| time  |      |       |      |       |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
| t0    | 10   | 110   | nan  | nan   |
| t1    | 10   | 110   |  9   |  97   |
| t2    | 12   | 109   |  9   |  97   |
| t3    | 12   | 109   | 15   |  94   |
| t5    | 12   | 109   | 13   | 100   |
| t6    | 20   | 108   | 13   | 100   |
+-------+------+-------+------+-------+
```

Is this possible?
If so, what steps would be required to go from the 2 dataframes read from csv, to the final merged multiindexed dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner that does what you ask, although it's a bit convoluted in terms of stacking/unstacking:

```
df1.append(df2).set_index(['time','id']).sort().stack().unstack(level=[1,2]).ffill()

id    ID1        ID2      
     size price size price
time                      
t0     10   110  NaN   NaN
t1     10   110    9    97
t2     12   109    9    97
t3     12   109   15    94
t5     12   109   13   100
t6     20   108   13   100
```

FWIW, my default approach would have been something like the following, which is a little more straightforward (less stacking/unstacking) and would give you the same basic results, but with a different column organization:

```
df1.append(df2).set_index(['time','id']).sort().unstack().ffill()

     size     price     
id    ID1 ID2   ID1  ID2
time                    
t0     10 NaN   110  NaN
t1     10   9   110   97
t2     12   9   109   97
t3     12  15   109   94
t5     12  13   109  100
t6     20  13   108  100
```

And along those lines, you could then add `swaplevel` and `sort` to get the columns reorganized to be like in the first approach:

```
df1.append(df2).set_index(['time','id']).sort().unstack().ffill().swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort(axis=1)
```

Comment: `df1.append(df2).set_index(['time','id'])` fails with `KeyError: u'no item named time'`. I think that's because `time` is the index, and `set_index` looks at the column headers. How would I specify to use the existing index `time` and also include column `id`?

Comment: The trick is to use `append` which adds a column to the existing index. `df1.append(fd2).set_index('id', append=True)`

Comment: OK looks like you figured it out.  I started with just the default [0,1,2,...] indexes in each one -- so `time` and `id` were just regular columns.  You could get to that via `reset_index()` or just do what you did, obviously.  I usually precede `set_index` with `reset_index` in those cases just to start with a blank slate for the index.